# c++ vector constructor and assignment questions

Tags: c++

I am confused as to what happens in line 2 and 3 of the following statements. To my understanding for

line2 (`vector<A> vec2(vec1);`
) : for each instance of A stored inside vec1, a copy constructor would be called and stored inside vec2. What confuses me is that even though i have not specified a custom copy constructor, the default copy constructor, creates an instance of A, probably calling default constructor of A and B, but THEN, actually correctly initlizes the original value of A's member array to the copy and A's member variable b's vector's values to the copy's B's vector. That is free deep copying. Is this correct?

line3 (`vector<A> vec3 = vec2;`) : instead of calling copy constructor, an instance of A would be created by default constructor and then stored instance's assigment operator would be called to initilize it. Here again, i am getting free deep copying.

```
1. vector<A> vec1;
2. vector<A> vec2(vec1);
3. vector<A> vec3 = vec2;
```

Where A is defined as shown below.

```
class B
{
public:
    vector<int> db;
};

class A
{
public:
    char data[5];
    int x;
    B bee;
};
```

Here is the main method to prove deep copying is happening

```
int main()
{
    A a, b;
    a.data = {'a','b','c','d','\0'};
    a.x = 1;
    a.bee.db.push_back(99);
    a.bee.db.push_back(100);


    b.data = {'z','x','y','w','\0'};
    b.x = 2;
    b.bee.db.push_back(1);
    b.bee.db.push_back(2);

    vector<A> vec;
    vec.push_back(a);
    vec.push_back(b);

    map<int, std::vector<A>> map1;
    vector<A> vec1(vec);

    map1[1] = vec1;

    std::vector<A> vec2 = map1[1];

    cout << vec2[0].data<< endl;
    cout << vec2[0].bee.db[0] << endl;

    vec2[0].x = 77777;
    vec2[0].data = {'c','o','p','y','\0'};

    cout << "vec1[0].x: " << vec1[0].x << endl;
    cout << "vec1[0].data: " << vec1[0].data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no assignment going on on line 3. It is called "copy initialization", and is quite equivalent to line 2 in this case.

Comment: What do you expect a shallow copy of `A` to do? How would it be different to a deep copy?

Comment: @juanchopanza   can you give an example using above context of an assignment, where assignment operator of A would be invoked?

Comment: @JonathanWakely i would expect shallow copy of A's array NOT to be initlized and shallow copy of A's member variable B's member variable vector to NOT be intilized.......

Comment: An assignment would be `vector<A> vec3; vec3 = vec2;`

Comment: Never use manual memory and copying is a piece of cake!

Comment: @Jimm, that's not what shallow copying means. It does not mean "uninitialized" it means "copies the raw bits of the source, not what those bits refer to". In your example the raw bits of your object _are_ the object's value, so a shallow copy completely copies the object's value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, all copy and assignment of `std::vector` are deep copy,
at least pre-C++11.  (In C++11, there are also versions which
involve move semantics.)

Second, your evaluation of:

```
`std::vector<A> vec3 = vec2;
```

is not really correct.  Because the type of `vec2` is the same
as that of the variable being initialized, this is exactly like
your case 2.  (If the types were different, formally,
a converting constructor will be called to convert the right
hand side to the correct type, and then the copy constructor
would be used.  But the compiler is allowed to optimize out the
copy.)

Also: if you had written:

```
std::vector<A> vec3;
vec3 = vec2;
```

The compiler would default construct an empty `vec3`, then
assign it.  But the assignment would still call the copy
constructor (and not the assignment operator) of each of the `A`
objects, because there aren't any constructed `A` objects in
`vec3` when you do the assignment (and assignment can only be to
a fully constructed object).

And finally: with regards to deep copy: `std::vector` copies as
deep as it knows, which are the contained elements.  Afterwards,
it is the responsibility of the contained elements to go deeper
(or not).  The default copy constructor will do a member by
member copy (so if all of the contained elements have copy
constructors, you're safe), but if there are e.g. raw pointers,
you may have to write your own, to give the object the copy
semantics you want.

Comment: can you point to the reference which states that vector copy and assignment are deep copies?

Comment: You may want to use "emplace_back", since its parameter is rvalue-referenced and sometimes faster.

Comment: @Jimm Just about every where there is anything about the
objects: the very first sentence in §32.2.1, for example.
Containers store objects, the copy constructor and assignment
operator copy the objects, etc.  There is no place where two
different containers can "contain" the same object.

Answer (score 3):

(1) Will result in a default constructed vector (as it appears you know).

(2) and (3) will both result in copy-constructed vectors from `vec1` and `vec2` respectively.

The vector copy constructor will copy construct each element of the source vector into the new vector. You get a free shallow copy from this copy implementation. For your particular objects `A` and `B` shallow and deep copy are exactly the same, so you effectively also wind up with a deep copy.

Comment: So in what case, shallow and deep copies would be the same? An array initlization, which ordinarily would require memcpy is free? and so is nested member's vector copying?

Comment: @Jimm Nothing is ever free. It just happens that the default copy for an array of `char` or a vector of int works out to be a deep copy. If it were an array or vector of raw pointers you would get a shallow copy (and need to be really careful about cleaing up to avoid double delete).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is shallow and Deep Copy Concept. According to me, it will not call Default C'tor i.e. it will directly call Default Copy C'tor in both the cases and By Default implementations is a shallow Copy since it will not take care of Memory Allocation of Data members if any.